# How to link to a different object fom a Django admin view?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created a custom admin class to display Comments Admin in my Django app. What I would like to do is for the items under "Object ID" to link to their respective objects' edit object page. How would I achieve that?

My Comments Admin:

```
class MyCommentsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (_('Content'),
           {'fields': ('user', 'user_name', 'user_email', 'user_url', 'comment')}
        ),
        (_('Metadata'),
           {'fields': ('submit_date', 'ip_address', 'is_public', 'is_removed')}
        ),
     )

    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'comment', 'content_type', 'object_pk', 'ip_address', 'submit_date', 'is_public', 'is_removed')
    list_filter = ('submit_date', 'site', 'is_public', 'is_removed')
    date_hierarchy = 'submit_date'
    list_display_links = ('id','comment',)
    ordering = ('-submit_date',)
    raw_id_fields = ('user',)
    search_fields = ('comment', 'user__username', 'user_name', 'user_email', 'ip_address')

admin.site.unregister(Comment)
admin.site.register(Comment, MyCommentsAdmin)
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Define a custom method on the admin class and reference that in your `list_display` tuple.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
class MyCommentsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'comment', 'content_type', 'object_link', 'ip_address', 'submit_date', 'is_public', 'is_removed')
    list_select_related = True

    def object_link(self, obj):
        ct = obj.content_type
        url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (ct.app_label, ct.model), args=(obj.id,)) 
        return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (url, obj.id)
    object_link.allow_tags = True
```

Note I've added `list_select_related=True`, as the object_link method references the content_type model, so it would otherwise cause a whole load of extra queries.

Comment: Thanks. There is a slight mistake here somewhere. The `id` that's returned is not the object's ID, but instead is the comment's own ID. How shall I fix this?

Comment: I changed `obj.id` to `obj.object_pk`. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Django 1.7 and needed to change `obj.content_type` to `obj._meta` and change `ct.model` to `ct.model_name`.

Comment: Actually for later versions than 1.7 also you have to do the same. Also `mark_safe_decorator` instead of `object_link.allow_tags = True` if you're using Django 2.

Answer (score 4):

This was a good answer but it has changed significantly.
This answer is more applicable to `Django 3.2.3`.

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class MyCommentsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = (
        'id', 'name', 'comment', 'content_type', 'object_link', 'ip_address',
        'submit_date', 'is_public', 'is_removed'
    )

    def object_link(self, obj):
        app_label = obj._meta.app_label
        model_label = obj._meta.model_name
        url = reverse(
            f'admin:{app_label}_{model_label}_change', args=(obj.id,)
        ) 
        return mark_safe(f'<a href="{url}">{obj.id}</a>')
```